# restassured is not setting Content-Type

Tags: java, automated-tests, rest-assured

I am using https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured (version 3.2.1) to test a REST API but I have problems setting Content-Type.

I am doing following test,

```
@Test
    public void testSendContentType(){
        String str = givenThat()
                .when()
                .contentType(ContentType.URLENC)
                .get(URL).asString();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

After executing the test I have following headers set.

**captured header**

```
Expires: Mon, 30 Jun 2014 14:33:21 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
```

I debugged and looked into the code but I am unable to understand how the content-type is set and why it is not setting the one I am providing.

I also tried following but didn't work

```
.header("Content-Type", ""application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the content type using:

```
given().contentType(ContentType.URLENC). ..
```

However it feels strange to have x-www-form-urlencoded for a GET request since a GET request shouldn't have a body. Usually REST Assured figures out that it should use x-www-form-urlencoded if you provide form parameters with the request.